# Run query connected to another database in VBA Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to run saved query inside VBA Access. That query is connected to another database and looks like that:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE IN 'C:\USERS\Another_database.accdb'
```

This query is saved as "My_query" inside first Access database. VBA code looks like this:

```
Function My_function()
     Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("My_query", dbOpenDynaset)
End Function
```

When I try to run it i got an error:

> Run-time error '3219'

Any ideas why? It works for normal queries (without `IN 'C:\USERS\Another_database.accdb'` part.

Comment: Why not just create a table linked to the other database?

Comment: I can do that. I've just tried to avoid creating those connections (database will be messy), but finally this solution will work. Thanks.

Comment: Messy? The linked table simply appears as a table, and it will run more efficiently than using `SELECT..IN` since the table will be properly indexed.  ... I'll post the method as an answer just to page sure we're on the same page (and since I have the screenshots ready anyhow!) ;-)

Comment: This code works for me. Please try to provide a [mcve], and provide the description for that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way to get data from another Access database on an ongoing basis is with **Linked Tables**.

- Click `External Data` on the ribbon, then `New Data Source` → `From Database` → `Access`
  [image: img1]
- <kbd>Browse</kbd> to the source database, and make sure you choose `Link to the data source by creating a linked table`
  [image: img2]
- Select one or more tables that you want to link
  [[image: img3]

The linked tables will be created [image: i] and you will be able to query the linked tables as if they were local to the current database.

---

### More Information:

- Office Support : [**Import or link to data in another Access database**](https://support.office.com/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6)
- Office Support: [**Manage Linked Tables**](https://support.office.com/article/manage-linked-tables-1d9346d6-953d-4f85-a9ce-4caec2262797)

Comment: Note that the approach desired in the answer provides a substantial advantage over linked tables. Since the link is established at runtime instead of ahead-of-time, design changes are handled gracefully, and it still can take advantage of things like indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to define a Recordset first or try to remove the quotation marks you have in the example? The following example works fine:

```
Dim rs as Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Field FROM Table IN 'here goes your path'")
```

Now you have an Array rs() in which you can loop.